# How to get row-column pair in a correlation matrix if its value goes beyond threshold in python?

Tags: python, dataframe

enter code hereI have a correlation matrix of size 50X50 and I would like to retain only those row-column pairs whose value goes above threshold.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,1,1,2], 
            'B':[5, 7, 3, 1, 2], 
            'C':[10, 20, 10, 12, 18]})

corr = df.corr()
corr
```

Output:

```
    A       B       C
A   1.00000 0.34114 0.97312
B   0.34114 1.00000 0.35411
C   0.97312 0.35411 1.00000
```

Now, given threshold 0.95, I'd like to get below output. Idea is to keep only highly correlated values in a corr matrix.

```
    A       B       C
A   1.00000 0       0.97312
B   0       1.00000 0
C   0.97312 0       1.00000
```

Comment: OK; your question is more likely to be answered if you post some code and example data; a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,1,1,2], 
        'B':[5, 7, 3, 1, 2], 
        'C':[10, 20, 10, 12, 18]})

corr = df.corr()
corr[corr < 0.95] = 0
corr
```